# After Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Laptop No Longer Shows When Plugged In

Tags: 22.04, power-management, battery

I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, from 18 with a brief time on 20. I don't recall if this problem showed up under 20 but I only noticed it under 22.

I have noticed that the indicator in the top right corner as well as the menu, and also the "Power" section in Settings (which is reached through selecting "Power Settings..." from the menu in the top-right) all do not show any notice or distinction between whether or not the laptop is plugged in.

Previously it would show whether or not the laptop was plugged in and I would get a visual indicator on the screen, I forget what it looked like, if it was a plug or a lightning bolt or something but there was something, whereas now it shows a battery icon, in such a way that suggests to me that it's not plugged in, but it is.

When I plug or unplug the cord, the power light flashes 3 times, as it always has.

I would like to know how to get this working the way it was before, where it shows me when the laptop is plugged in. This is highly relevant because I sometimes forge to plug the laptop in and leave it for a long period of time, and I want a visual reminder of whether I am on battery power or not.

It's also not clear to me whether there is any other problem here, but I'm a little worried that if the system is misreading whether or not the laptop is plugged in, that it might not be charging it properly, although I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I haven't run into any problems, though.